Bathroom fan air leaking air into bathroom
The bathroom fan is definitely drawing air up in the centre as seen in the video and it’s blowing air into the room on the side near where the plug outlet is. At first I thought I needed to find a fan that went in the opposite direction but once I sat with the fan in my hands and turned it manually while eyeballing where the vent hole is, I thought well maybe it’s NIT the fan direction after all. Bought a new fan it goes the same direction.
I shone a light up and noticed a space between the metal plate inside and the top of the box so I thought maybe air is escaping there. I took the aluminum tape and sealed it up and that doesn’t make a difference either.
I guess the next step would be to take the entire box and all out but I don’t know how to do that without cutting the ceiling drywall which I don’t want to do. To install the new one I’d have to nail it to the stud so the drywall would need to be gone for that too.
So on top of alll that, does anyone have any further suggestions?

Here’s a video of the fan sucking and blowing.  :)
https://imgur.com/a/97XWpsR

Have you checked that the duct isn't plugged?  Maybe birds got in the outlet end and built a nest.  That would cause the symptoms you're seeing.

If the exit duct is that narrow for any length, you'll get back pressure even without an obstruction. And with such a narrow exit I'd expect a little back flow round the edges anyway, but a very small proportion of the total.

Yes, if you know where the exit is, and if it's accessible, you should be able to determine whether or not the duct is clear with a vacuum.  Like get a shop vac and stuff the hose in the hole, and pack a towel around it to seal it up.
